# How to add indexes using langchine PGVector() and retrive using index to be used in RAG chain?

Tags: langchain, pgvector

db = PGVector(embedding_function=embeddings, collection_name= case_id,connection_string = CONNECTION_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/templates/rag-multi-index-router/rag_multi_index_router/chain.py) that creates a multi-index router in Langchain's repo.

Although they are using the `ArxivRetriever`, `KayAiRetriever`, `PubMedRetriever`, and `WikipediaRetriever`, I don't see why you cannot create two separate collections with `PGVector` and then use the [as_retriever()](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/pgvector#using-a-vectorstore-as-a-retriever) method to convert them to `Retriever` objects, i.e.:

```py
retriever_one = PGVector(...).as_retriever().with_config(run_name="retriever_one")
retriever_two = PGVector(...).as_retriever().with_config(run_name="retriever_two")
```

Then, use [LangChain's Router](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/foundational/router), as seen in the example repo, to create a [Runnable](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/interface), which "makes it easy to define custom chains as well as invoke them in a standard way":

```py
from langchain.schema.runnable import RouterRunnable

retriever_map = {
    "one": retriever_one,
    "two": retriever_two,
}
router_retriever = RouterRunnable(runnables=retriever_map)
```

You can then use `router_retriever` in any chain, as you can see in the example linked above:

```py
retriever_chain = (
    {"input": itemgetter("question"), "key": itemgetter("retriever_choice")}
    | router_retriever  # here's your router_retriever
    | format_docs
).with_config(run_name="retrieve")
answer_chain = (
    {"sources": retriever_chain, "question": itemgetter("question")}
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)
```

I haven't tested this myself, but this should do the trick.